# What syntax is allowed when applying C# attributes?

Tags: c#, syntax, attributes

These are the most common and only patterns I have seen so far:

```
[AttributeFoo]
[AttributeBar("Hello world!")]
[AttributeBaz(foo=42,bar="Hello world!")]
public class Example {}
```

The attribute syntax *looks like* you're calling a constructor. And before C# supported optional and named arguments, named parameters for attributes were the only visible difference.

Does the C# compiler allow anything else? Like `params` arguments or object/collection initializers?

See also: [Applying Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: I once put a `string[]` initializer in an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, named parameters only permit integral types. Unfortunately i do not have a reference to back this up, I only learnt it through my own experimentation.

When trying to use object initialisers, I got this error from the compiler:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Although this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a few years old, it has the reference information I was looking for:

> Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the
>   following types:
>
> - Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
> - string
> - System.Type
> - enums
> - object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above    types.) One-dimensional
>     arrays of any of the above types

So this works:

```
//Test attribute class
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
internal class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int[] Something { get; set; }
}

//Using an array initialiser - an array of integers
[TestAttribute(Something = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})]
public abstract class Something
```

Whereas this wouldn't:

```
//Test person class
internal class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

//Test attribute class
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
internal class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Something { get; set; }
}

//This won't work as Person is not an integral type
[TestAttribute(Something = new Person[]{new Person("James")})]
```

EDIT: just to elaborate, attributes form part of the metadata for constructs they are applied to (within the generated IL), thus the members of the attribute class must be determined at compile time; hence the restriction on attribute parameters to constant values.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what others have said, I'd like to point out that attributes can also be comma separated.

```
[AttributeFoo, AttributeBar("Hello world!"), AttributeBaz(foo=42,bar="Hello world!")]
public class Example {}
```

Comment: IMHO it's more readable if they dont have parameters, and if you look at the code as a whole. `[AttributeA, AttributeB, AttributeC]`.

Answer (score 1):

> Positional parameters are required and must come before any named parameters; they correspond to the parameters of one of the attribute's constructors. Named parameters are optional and correspond to read/write properties of the attribute. In C++, C#, and J#, specify name=value for each optional parameter, where name is the name of the property. In Visual Basic, specify name:=value.

From the link you provided. It looks like those are the only things allowed. Basically you are combining the constructor with embedded property initialization logic, as you mentioned.

Comment: While I think this is a long way towards answering the question, it is missing discussion of what types of expressions are allowed for the arguments themselves. E.g., constants, array creation expressions, `typeof()` expressions, etc.